# Dynamic Drop-down search bar results do not parse into my List for Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm creating a simple script to visit *priceline.com* and then searching "**N**" under **Departing Flights** and selecting **New York City (NYC)** from the dropdown list.

My code successfully types into the search bar but is still unable to find the dynamic dropdown with all the relevant results. I am not sure why.

```
// Clicks on "Departing from?" textbox and clears it before typing 'N'
driver.findElement(By.id("flight-departure-airport0")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("flight-departure-airport0")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("flight-departure-airport0")).sendKeys("N");

// Store all dynamic search results into a list
List<WebElement> departureDropdown = driver.findElements(By.id("//*['flight-departure-airport0-dropdown']/div/div/div"));

System.out.println("List: "+departureDropdown);
```

**Expected:**
I expected `departureDropdown` to have a length of 9 with various airports. (Nadi, New York City, Nagasaki, etc) and expect `departureDropdown[i]` to return one of the city names in plain text.

**Actual:**
My code is stuck at the list initialization. `departureDropdown` is empty.

Comment: You have printed a list which is object. Have you checked that list size?

Comment: No I have not, my last print statement did not even run so I have no output to troubleshoot with. I will try your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: That is because your driver.findElements failed, you have used By.id and expected is By.xPath. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used By.id but you have created xPath.

Try with below xPath

```
List<WebElement> departureDropdown = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//div[@id='flight-departure-airport0-dropdown']//div[@role='option']"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this led me to the right result.
`System.out.println("Dynamic Search");
List<WebElement> departureDropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='flight-departure-airport0-dropdown']/div/div/div"));
System.out.println("List: "+departureDropdown.get(0).getText());`

I guess the only way is to creating a String Array and pass getText() to each one. Thank you